# Multichannel PyAudio with ASIO Support

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio, asio

I'm attempting to interface to a PreSonus AudioBox 1818VSL with PyAudio on Win7, but am having some trouble recording more than 2 channels (stereo) at a time. The PreSonus driver creates many stereo input audio devices (ex. stereo channels 1&2, 3&4, etc.) and an 18 input channel ASIO device.  I can record from any of the stereo devices without issue. To minimize latency and record from > 2 channels, I'm trying to use the ASIO device.

I've been using a build of PyAudio from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio, which has compiled support for ASIO, DS, WMME, WASAPI, WDMKS.

Calls to `pyaudio_handle.is_format_supported()` show the ASIO device supports 8 to 32-bit data at 44.1, 48, and 96 kHz.

Below is the dictionary returned by `pa.get_device_info_by_index(32)`

```
{'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.046439909297052155,
'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.046439909297052155,
'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.046439909297052155,
'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.046439909297052155,
'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0,
'hostApi': 2L,
'index': 32,
'maxInputChannels': 18L,
'maxOutputChannels': 18L,
'name': u'AudioBox ASIO Driver',
'structVersion': 2L}
```

Below is the code that I have been using to create the PyAudio input stream. The callback function simply pushes the data into a list and returns `pyaudio.paContinue` until I get the amount of samples I want, then it returns `pyaudio.paComplete`.

```
pyaudio_handle = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pyaudio_handle.open(
    format=pyaudio.get_format_from_width(2,unsigned=False),
    channels=4,
    rate=48000,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=256,
    input_device_index=32,
    stream_callback=pyaudio_stream_callback,
)
```

Attempting to initialize the ASIO driver at rates faster than 44.1 kHz cause PyAudio to hang and not return. Initializing at 44.1 kHz produces the following error: `IOError: [Errno Unanticipated host error] -9999`.

Any help that you can provide resolving this error would be helpful. I would even settle for proof that ASIO works with > 2 channels in PyAudio when running on Win7.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to record 8 channel audio (M-audio M-Track Eight) using the ASIO driver at 96 kHZ.

From

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
p.get_device_info_by_index(4)
```

I found that 'index': 4 was the ASIO driver:

```
{'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.005804988662131519, 
 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.09287981859410431, 
 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.005804988662131519,
 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 
 'maxInputChannels': 8, 
 'maxOutputChannels': 8,
 'structVersion': 2, 
 'name': 'M-Audio M-Track Eight ASIO', 
 'index': 4, 
 'hostApi': 2,
 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.09287981859410431}
```

So I started with the sample code on [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) but switched from wave to **`scipy.io.wavfile`** to write the multichannel .wav file since `wave` only supports stereo.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavefile

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 8
RATE = 96000
RECORD_SECONDS = 10
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                input_device_index=4,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
                )

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()


#Not really sure what b'' means in BYTE STRING but numpy needs it 
#just like wave did...
framesAll = b''.join(frames)

#Use numpy to format data and reshape.  
#PyAudio output from stream.read() is interlaced.
result = np.fromstring(framesAll, dtype=np.int16)
chunk_length = len(result) / CHANNELS
result = np.reshape(result, (chunk_length, CHANNELS))

#Write multi-channel .wav file with SciPy
wavfile.write(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME,RATE,result)
```

Viola! 96 kHz, 16-bit, 8 channel .wav file!

Oh, details

- Win7 64bit
- M-Audio Eight 64 bit Windows Driver 1.0.11
- Python 3.4.2 32 bit
- PyAudio 0.2.8 for Win7 from
  [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
- numpy-1.9.2
- scipy-0.15.1-win32-superpack-python3.4

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to record more than two tracks with the build of PyAudio from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio). Also I found the same problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734495/9314452 written by @Laughingrice.

So I compiled portaudio with Microsoft Visual Studio (free version) according to

http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows_asio_msvc.html
http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html

Note that we have to download ASIO SDK library from https://www.steinberg.net/developers for ASIO support.

Then I also built pyaudio with the portaudio_x64.dll (compiled with MSVC) like:

```
python setup.py build_ext -I .\portaudio\include -L .\portaudio\mybuild\Release -l portaudio_x86
python setup.py install
```

When I met an error message:

```
>>> import pyaudio
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\subf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyAudio-0.2.12-py3.10-win-amd64.egg\pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _portaudio: DLL load failed
```

I solved the problem by coping the portaudio DLL to the directory of pyaudio library directly:

```
copy portaudio_x64.dll C:\Users\myid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyAudio-0.2.12-py3.10-win-amd64.egg
```

I succeeded in recording more than two channels with pyaudio.

And I made separate wav files because the wave file format has 2 GB limitation.

```
wavfile.write( "channel_01.wav", RATE, result[:,0] )
wavfile.write( "channel_02.wav", RATE, result[:,1] )
wavfile.write( "channel_03.wav", RATE, result[:,2] )
wavfile.write( "channel_04.wav", RATE, result[:,3] )
wavfile.write( "channel_05.wav", RATE, result[:,4] )
wavfile.write( "channel_06.wav", RATE, result[:,5] )
wavfile.write( "channel_07.wav", RATE, result[:,6] )
...
```

Now I am trying to record automatically (by nnCron freeware) multi-track with pyaudio from beringer X32 at every worship service in a church.